# WordPress - host Uploads directory to remote server via FTP or sFTP

Tags: wordpress, ftp, sftp

I have 2 servers - 
1. Application server - where WordPress application are hosted and 
2. Media server - where all media files (like images, pdf, etc.) are hosted

I am trying to upload all images directly via FTP. But to achieve this through FTP connection, I have to upload images on application server's Upload folder, then read all images one by one and then move all images to Media server. Once all images moved to Media server, I need to delete these images from Application server. These process too costly and is not working if multiple images have same name.

Is there any code, by which I can upload all images to Media server via FTP, without storing it to Application server. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you hosting the WordPress and Media server in a Linux or Windows server?

Comment: Both servers are on Linux server.

Comment: If you have SSH access, you can do rsync which will sync all files in the upload folder of Application server to upload folder of media server.

Comment: Yes, I can do but still this is double work - first upload to application server then sync with Media server. Can we not upload all images directly to Media server? Please suggest. Thanks

Comment: I'm not aware of any direct method to set the WordPress upload directory on a different server. One solution which I can think of is to add the upload folder of media server as a NFS mount on application server.